# spl_autoload_register on Ubuntu

Tags: php, class, ubuntu, autoload

I'm trying to use the **spl_autoload_register** in PHP to auto load classes in /lib/classes/ directory of my project.

So including this into my boot file

```
require_once('lib/classes/Autoloader.php');
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');
```

Inside Autoloader.php

```
class Autoloader
{
    public static function loader($class)
    {
        $filename = strtolower($class) . '.php';
        $file ='lib/classes/' . $filename;
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            echo 'Class '.$class. ' not found'.PHP_EOL;
            return false;
        }
        echo 'Including class '.$class.PHP_EOL;
        include $file;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on Windows IIS and loads the classes in lib/classes/ however on Ubuntu it cannot find the classes, so I presume there is something different in the way Ubuntu includes file paths?

Any ideas how I can fix this so it works on Windows and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use absolute paths, however to keep consistency, you can use the function [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) in your boot file and assuming that the folder `lib` is on the same level relative to your boot file.

```
define('ROOT_FOLDER',dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT_FOLDER.'/lib/classes/Autoloader.php');
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');
```